# How to do AuthContext, createDataContext using Typescript for React Native Expo dev?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

***AuthContext.tsx***

```
import createDataContext from './createDataContext';
import serverApi from '../api/server';

const authReducer = ({state, action}: any) => { 
    switch(action.type){
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const signup = () => {
    return  async ({email, password}: any) => {
        try{
            const response = await serverApi.post('/signup', {email, password});
            console.log(response.data)
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    };
}

const signin = ({dispatch}:any) => {
    return ({email, password}: any) => {    };
}

const signout = ({dispatch}: any) => {
    return () => {};
}

export const {Provider, Context} = createDataContext(
    authReducer,
    {signin, signout, signup},
    {isSignedIn: false}
);
```

***createDataContext***

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

export default ({reducer, actions, defaultValue}: any) => {
    const Context = React.createContext();

    const Provider = ({ children }: any) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);
    
        const boundActions: any = {};
        for (let key in actions) {
          boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
        }
    
        return (
          <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
            {children}
          </Context.Provider>
        );
      };
    
      return { Context, Provider };
}
```

I copy the code from a video tutorial where react native app has been developed with js extension. But the project I am working on has tsx extension i.e. TypeScript.
**How to convert the above code so it will work in my typescript react native mobile app?**

Answer (score 0):

`({reducer, actions, defaultValue}: any)` is expecting **one** argument with three properties.  But when you call it, you are passing three separate arguments. So you want `(reducer: any, actions: any, defaultValue: any)`.  Likewise, a reducer takes two arguments so you want `authReducer = (state: any, action: any) =>`, and so on for a bunch of your functions.

Now we want to get rid of all the `any` and use actual types!  Some of those types we can import from `react` and others we will define ourselves.

The part that's tricky is getting your context to know the types for your specific action creators and what arguments each one requires.  You want this so that you can get autocomplete suggestions for the actions and so you can know if you are calling them improperly.   But that requires more advanced typescript like [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) so just copy and paste this and don't worry too much.

```
import React, { useReducer, FunctionComponent, Reducer, Dispatch } from 'react';

interface DataState {
  isSignedIn: boolean;
  // add any other properties here
}

interface SignInProps {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

// you can change this
// it is common to use a type for `Action` that is a union of your specific actions
interface Action {
  type: string;
  payload: any;
}

// this is where I am getting tricky
type BoundActions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (d: Dispatch<Action>) => infer R ? R : never
}
type ContextValue<T> = {
  state: DataState;
} & BoundActions<T>

export const createDataContext = <T extends {}>(reducer: Reducer<DataState, Action>, actions: T, defaultValue: DataState) => {
  // context needs a defaultValue
  const Context = React.createContext({state: defaultValue} as ContextValue<T>);

  // type of children is known by assigning the type FunctionComponent to Provider
  const Provider: FunctionComponent = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);

    const boundActions = {} as BoundActions<T>;
    for (let key in actions) {
      // @ts-ignore - I don't want to make a confusing mess so just ignore this
      boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
    }

    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  };

  return { Context, Provider };
}

const authReducer = (state: DataState, action: Action): DataState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const signup = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
  return async ({ email, password }: SignInProps) => {
    try {
      const response = await serverApi.post('/signup', { email, password });
      console.log(response.data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
}

const signin = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
  return ({ email, password }: SignInProps) => { };
}

const signout = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
  return () => { };
}

export const { Provider, Context } = createDataContext(
  authReducer,
  { signin, signout, signup },
  { isSignedIn: false }
);
```

The point of doing all that is to get intellisense and type checking when you consume the context.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Provider, Context } from .... // your path

const SampleComponent = () => {
  // knows all of the properties available on the context
  const {state, signin, signout, signup} = useContext(Context);

  const handleClick = () => {
    // knows that these need email and password
    signin({email: '', password: ''});
    signup({email: '', password: ''});
    // knows that this one is ok to call with no args
    signout();
  }

  return (
    <div>{state.isSignedIn ? "Signed In!" : "Not Signed In"}</div>
  )
}

const SampleApp = () => (
  <Provider>
    <SampleComponent/>
  </Provider>
)
```